Magento 2 How to place order PROGRAMMATICALLY using custom script
How to place an order for testing while developing order-related tasks. using the custom script we will save our time to add products from the website and checkout flow. It will be passed using a custom script.

@Vikas Kalal
Hey,
Use the following data to create quote and order:
<?php
$order = [
    'currency_id' => 'USD',
    'email' => 'hello@example.com',
    'shipping_address' => ['firstname' => 'John',
        'lastname' => 'Doe',
        'street' => 'xxxxxx',
        'city' => 'xxxxxxx',
        'country_id' => 'US',
        'region' => 'xxxxx',
        'postcode' => '85001',
        'telephone' => '52556542',
        'fax' => '3242322556',
        'save_in_address_book' => 1],
    'items' => [
        ['product_id' => '1', 'qty' => 1],
        ['product_id' => '2', 'qty' => 2]]
    ];
?>

The order create function in module helper file is as follows:
<?php
namespaceYourNameSpace\ModuleName\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context, \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formkey, \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement, \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory, \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository, \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService $orderService)
    {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->formkey = $formkey;
        $this->quote = $quote;
        $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->orderService = $orderService;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function createOrder($order)
    {
        $store = $this->storeManager->getStore();
        $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customer->loadByEmail($order['email']); // load customet by email address
       if (!$customer->getEntityId()) {
            //If not avilable then create this customer
           $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)->setStore($store)->setFirstname($order['shipping_address']['firstname'])->setLastname($order['shipping_address']['lastname'])->setEmail($order['email'])->setPassword($order['email']);
            $customer->save();
        }
        $quote = $this->quote->create(); // Create Quote Object
       $quote->setStore($store); // Set Store
       $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
        $quote->setCurrency();
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer); // Assign quote to Customer

        //add items in quote
       foreach ($order['items'] as $item) {
            $product = $this->product->load($item['product_id']);
            $product->setPrice($item['price']);
            $quote->addProduct($product, intval($item['qty']));
        }

        $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($order['shipping_address']);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($order['shipping_address']);

        // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method

       $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping');
        $quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');
        $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false);
        $quote->save();

        // Set Sales Order Payment
       $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);

        // Collect Totals & Save Quote
       $quote->collectTotals()->save();

        // Create Order From Quote
       $orderdata = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);

        $orderdata->setEmailSent(0);
        $increment_id = $order->getRealOrderId();
        if ($orderdata->getEntityId()) {
            $result['order_id'] = $orderdata->getRealOrderId();
        } else {
            $result = ['error' => 1, 'msg' => 'Your custom message'];
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
?>

Thank You!

Here is the custom script that helps us to place test orders using the COD payment method. Put the script below in the media directory and run it in the browser your order will get placed successfully.
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    require '../app/bootstrap.php';
    
    
    $orderInfo =[
        'currency_id'  => 'USD',
        'email'        => 'vikas@gmail.com', //customer email id
        'shipping_address' =>[
            'firstname'    => 'Vikas',
            'lastname'     => 'Kalal',
            'prefix' => '',
            'suffix' => '',
            'street' => 'B1 Abcd street',
            'city' => 'Los Angeles',
            'country_id' => 'US',
            'region' => 'California',
            'region_id' => '12', // State region id
            'postcode' => '45454',
            'telephone' => '1234512345',
            'fax' => '12345',
            'save_in_address_book' => 0
        ],
        'items'=>
            [
                ['product_id'=>'31','qty'=>2], //simple product
                ['product_id'=>'318','qty'=>1], //simple product
                ['product_id'=>'282','qty'=>2] //configurable product, pass super_attribte for configurable product
            ]
    ];
    
    class customScript
    {
        /**
         * @param Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
         * @param Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
         * @param Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
         * @param Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepositoryInterface,
         * @param Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $cartManagementInterface,
         * @param Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
         

* @param Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
         * @param Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
         */
        public function __construct(){
            $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
            $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
            $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
            $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
            $this->_storeManager = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class);
            $this->_product = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::class);
            $this->cartRepositoryInterface = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface::class);;
            $this->cartManagementInterface = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface ::class);;
            $this->customerFactory = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory::class);;
            $this->customerRepository = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface::class);;
            $this->order = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::class);;
        }
    
        /**
         * Create Order On Your Store
         *
         * @param array $orderData
         * @return array
         *
         */
        public function createMageOrder($orderData)
        {
            $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
            $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
            $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
            $customer->loadByEmail($orderData['email']);// load customet by email address
            if (!$customer->getEntityId()) {
                //If not avilable then create this customer
                $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                    ->setStore($store)
                    ->setFirstname($orderData['shipping_address']['firstname'])
                    ->setLastname($orderData['shipping_address']['lastname'])
                    ->setEmail($orderData['email'])
                    ->setPassword($orderData['email']);
                $customer->save();
            }
    
            $cartId = $this->cartManagementInterface->createEmptyCart(); //Create empty cart
            $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cartId); // load empty cart quote
            $quote->setStore($store);
            // if you have allready buyer id then you can load customer directly
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
            $quote->setCurrency();
            $quote->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer
            //add items in quote
            foreach ($orderData['items'] as $item) {
                $product = $this->_product->load($item['product_id']);
                $quote->addProduct($product, intval($item['qty']));
            }
            //Set Address to quote
            $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
            // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
            $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
            $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                ->collectShippingRates()
                ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate'); //shipping method
            $quote->setPaymentMethod('cashondelivery'); //payment method
            $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false); //not effetc inventory
            // Set Sales Order Payment
            $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'cashondelivery']);
            $quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready
            // Collect Totals
            $quote->collectTotals();
            // Create Order From Quote
            $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($quote->getId());
            $orderId = $this->cartManagementInterface->placeOrder($quote->getId());
            $order = $this->order->load($orderId);
    
            $order->setEmailSent(0);
            $increment_id = $order->getRealOrderId();
            if ($order->getEntityId()) {
                $result['order_id'] = $order->getRealOrderId();
            } else {
                $result = ['error' => 1, 'msg' => 'Your custom message'];
            }
            return $result;
        }
    }
    $objOrder = new customScript();
    $result   = $objOrder->createMageOrder($orderInfo);
    echo "<pre>";print_r($result);
    ?>

